# python partial derivatives, I can't use this with numeric

Tags: python, ode, differential-equations

I have a function who I neeed to make to it  partial derivatives dependent on a parameter and to use this in another function, and then to solve an ODE system, The function who I need to derivate is anizotropy_energy with respect of theta and phi

```
import sympy
import numpy as np
from sympy import Symbol, diff, sin, cos


theta = Symbol('theta')
phi = Symbol('phi')
theta_k = Symbol('theta_k')
phi_k = Symbol('phi_k')

def anizotropy_energy(theta, phi, theta_k, phi_k):

    u_rx = sin(theta)*sin(phi)
    u_ry = sin(theta)*sin(phi)
    u_rz = cos(theta)
    u_kx = sin(theta_k)*cos(phi_k)
    u_ky = sin(theta_k)*sin(phi_k)
    u_kz = cos(theta_k)

    u_kx*u_rx + u_ky*u_ry + u_kz*u_rz

    diff((u_kx*u_rx + u_ky*u_ry + u_kz*u_rz)**2, theta)
```

I made it with sympy, but I can't use these derrivates in odeint
I have an intermediate function where I a have to add to a structure with theta and phi this derrivates and then to use this function in the main program with Ode

Intermediate function:

```
import math
import numpy as np


from anisotropy_energy  import anizotropy_energy

def thetafunc_anisotropy(alpha,theta,phi, hx, hy, hz, theta_k, phi_k):


   return alpha*(hx*np.cos(theta)*np.cos(phi) +       hy*np.cos(theta)*np.sin(phi)- \
hz*np.sin(theta) + \
anizotropy_energy(theta, phi, theta_k, phi_k) + \
(-hx*np.sin(phi) + hy*np.cos(phi))
 #    diff(anizotropy_energy(theta, phi, theta_k, phi_k), phi) )
```

The main programme:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import thetafunc_anizotropy
from  thetafunc_anizotropy import thetafunc_anisotropy
import phifunc_anizotropy
from phifunc_anizotropy import phifunc_anisotropy
import sympy

def LLG(y, t, alpha, hx, hy, hz, theta_k, phi_k):

   theta, phi = y

   dydt = [thetafunc_anisotropy(alpha,theta,phi, hx, hy, hz, theta_k, phi_k), thetafunc_anisotropy(alpha,theta,phi, hx, hy, hz, theta_k, phi_k)]

  return dydt

alpha = 0.1


H = 1.0
t0 = 60.0*np.pi/180.0
p0 = 0.0*np.pi/180.0
hx = H*np.sin(t0)*np.cos(p0)
hy = H*np.sin(t0)*np.sin(p0)
hz = H*np.cos(t0)

theta_k = 60.0*np.pi/180.0 
phi_k = 60.0*np.pi/180.0



y0 = [np.pi, -0*np.pi]  
t = np.linspace(0, 1000, 10000)


sol = odeint(LLG, y0, t, args=(alpha,hx, hy, hz, theta_k, phi_k ))   
print sol

mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10
#
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
#x = np.sol[:, 0]
#y = sol[:, 1]
#ax.plot(x, y, label='parametric curve')
#ax.legend()
x = np.sin(sol[:, 0])*np.cos(sol[:, 1])
y = np.sin(sol[:, 0])*np.sin(sol[:, 1]) 
z =  np.cos(sol[:, 0])
ax.plot(x, y, z, label='parametric curve')
ax.legend()
#plt.show()
#plt.axes(projection='3d')
#plt.plot(t, sol[:, 0], 'b', label='$\\theta(t)$')
#plt.plot(t,sol[:,1], 'r', label='$\\varphi(t)$')
# 
#plt.legend(loc='best')
#plt.xlabel('t')
#
#plt.grid()
#plt.show()
```

Comment: Should it not be `u_rx = sin(theta)*cos(phi)`?

Answer (score 2):

Your error is in anizotropy_energy.py. You have global variables with the same name as function parameters. 
In this case you have a global named theta and phi AND function parameters named theta and phi. You must rename one pair of them.
I labeled the function parameters theta and phi to in_theta and in_phi. You should really rename them.

Also, **Note** that in some places you say ani**s**otropy and some you say ani**z**otropy.

```
import sympy
import numpy as np
from sympy import Symbol, diff, sin, cos


theta = Symbol('theta')
phi = Symbol('phi')
theta_k = Symbol('theta_k')
phi_k = Symbol('phi_k')

def anizotropy_energy(in_theta, in_phi, theta_k, phi_k):

    u_rx = sin(in_theta)*sin(in_phi)
    u_ry = sin(in_theta)*sin(in_phi)
    u_rz = cos(in_theta)
    u_kx = sin(theta_k)*cos(phi_k)
    u_ky = sin(theta_k)*sin(phi_k)
    u_kz = cos(theta_k)

    u_kx*u_rx + u_ky*u_ry + u_kz*u_rz

    return diff((u_kx*u_rx + u_ky*u_ry + u_kz*u_rz)**2, theta)
```